# java not updating "Failed to download required installation files."

Tags: windows-7, java

On my Windows 7 machine the Java update consistently fails with this error message.This seems to a common problem, does anyone have an insight into what's going wrong, and is there a fix for it other than either disabling the update check (seems a bad idea from a security point of view) or waiting for the nag message and then manually installing the new version (annoying and stupid from a usability point of view).

[image: Failed to download required installation files.]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this specific problem, but I would download ReVo Uninstaller, free - and portable if you prefer:

https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo-uninstaller-free-download/

This is the definitely **best** application to uninstall seriously, removing everything left by other applications, like register keys and values, files  everywhere including in user/appdata, etc.

Maybe try to properly uninstall the old one with this tool, eventually reboot, and then have a clean install of the most recent. See if that works, at the next update?